# HDMI not working in debian 11, should I update my graphics driver?

Tags: debian, intel-graphics, hdmi

- Debian 11 laptop
- Graphics Driver: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)

When I plug in a HDMI connection from my laptop to my TV it doesn't connect. When I run `xrandr` the output isn't shown either.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.03 +  60.01*   59.97    59.96    59.93    40.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

A while ago it used to work, when I was using PopOS but then abruptly stopped. I thought moving to another distro would help but nope, HDMI still does not work with debian 11. My best lead a post telling me to update my graphics driver but I don't know how to do that safely. Is this what I should do or is there an easier solution?

I see that alot of people have asked the same question and I'm sorry to pile on to that but I don't really know what to do honestly.
(No it is not the HDMI cable nor is it any combination of plugging the cable in and restarting the computer)

Comment: Maybe you need to add the laptop anew or select it anew in the TV so this may not be an issue of your computer. If that didn't help, try lowering the resolution and frame-rate and connect the cable again and change it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of NVIDIA there's no concept of drivers in Linux: everything instead is tied to either or both your kernel version and Mesa version. The latter is responsible for OpenGL/Vulkan.

If you need newer "drivers" you install a newer kernel release or Mesa release and hope it works for you. If even the latest stable kernel (5.18.6 at the time of writing) doesn't work for you, you file a bug report in the appropriate bug trackers.

For intel that would be https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues

This also means that distro hopping doesn't make a lot (if any) sense. What makes sense is knowing that you distro contains a kernel which works for you. If you want to run the latest stable kernel you're welcome to use Fedora or Arch Linux. Probably there are others but I don't follow.

Debian, considering its update policy, is generally recommended for old enough PCs and laptops (more than 3-5 years of age).

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar problem. A TV was working on HDMI-1 / DEBIAN 11 on LENOVO GR70 with default GPU installed. Suddenly stopped working. I did even see the secondary display working at boot start and dissappear during boot.

So it can be something else than kernel or driver problem.

In syslog I found:

> lenovo kernel: [ 5931.313048] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] HPD interrupt
> storm detected on connector HDMI-A-1: switching from hotplug detection
> to polling May 15 17:54:23 lenovo org.kde.KScreen[4712]:  #011Output:
> 67 ( "HDMI-1" )

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/445344)